# Why does my two containers (created using docker compose) aren't able to see each other except both of them are published?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers, one container is my next.js app and the other one is mongodb.

I create them by using `docker compose up`

Although they're on the same network it looks like they can't see each other. ( I verified this due to [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) and also `docker network inspect` command)

my `compose.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" 
  db:
    image: mongo:4.4.6
    expose: 
      - "27017"
```

If I publish both of them it works just fine ( I refer the database URL as `mongodb://db:27017/database` in my `.env.local`)

But as a best practice I should only publish the app and expose the db to the app.

the working `compose.yml` file is:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" 
  db:
    image: mongo:4.4.6
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the "depends_on" section in your app specification. By adding it, you indicate that your app depends on your db service and will start only once the service is ready. It should look like this:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" 
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mongo:4.4.6
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
```